# How to restart kernel in VSCode to completely reload imports?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I change an imported python script when running cell by cell imports doesn't work until I restart the whole program VSCode. I tried to kill kernel and restart it, saved changes - nothing works, only restarting is need. But it isn't too quick and appropriate to restart it each time I change the code.
Is there any way to apply changes in imported scripts? I am on linux lubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Execute those lines after your imports and any saved changes you make to the external file you are importing should get automatically reflected.

Comment: Where should I execute these lines? In the terminal of VSCode?

Comment: Yes, I just put these in my python code under all my import lines in the editor. So lets say I have master.py open in the editor. I would have "import mymodule as my", then the autoreload lines, and then any call in my script like normal as needed (my.method()...). With the autoreload lines executed with the import lines, any changes I save to mymodule.py will be reflected when I re-execute any calls to mymodule from master.py. (mymodule.py needs to be in the same folder as master.py, of course).

Answer (score 0):

> When I change an imported python script when running cell by cell imports doesn't work until I restart the whole program VSCode.

If you are trying to change and save an imported python file, running cell by cell does not work like that. You will have to save all the changes in first go, and then try executing cell by cell; that is because in cell by cell execution in VSCode is handled by a stack and no exclusive information like unchanged data/status is available to that stack. That's why you'll have to first make all the changes, and then execute.

Comment: What does it mean "save all the changes in first go"? I tried to save all changes and then restart kernel and import from the beginning. But it doesn't help.

Comment: You previously might have interrupted the execution abruptly, and then tried saving and then executing. This should not have been interrupted.

Comment: No I haven't. Every running cell finished correctly

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to this problem is using `importlib`:

```
import my_changed_module as mc
import importlib

importlib.reload(mc)
```

This will reload your module everytime you run your script.